# statusbar / header appears in iOS-11. How will i hide it?

Tags: ionic-framework, ios11, xcode9

I made an ionic application. **Still works perfectly in iOS-9 and iOS-10.**

Today, i update **iOS-10 to iOS-11 and i also update xcode-8 to xcode-9.**

**There is a strange issue in iOS-11. See below image for the issue.**

[image]

When, i was build the app in xcode8 and ios10, the header/stautsbar was not appears.

But, when i update xcode8 to xcode9 and ios10 to ios11 then this issue occurs.

Please tell me, how should i hide it or make it transparent.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

finally i found a solution.

i installed plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-disable-ios11-statusbar --save
```

Then build and run the app the issue will be solved

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your viewport meta tag `viewport-fit=cover`

Answer (score 1):

[check the blog (iOS 11 Checklist)](https://blog.ionic.io/ios-11-checklist/)

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-statusbar
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git
```